# Show content based on a few parameters

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

A little lost - Just trying to find the correct order for this to work.

I have a template that is to output a value based on the following parameter.

I have a wordpress running with a custom post type for courses, and additional custom fields for each course like "Department ID"

Based on a "options page" setup with ACF i want to decide if a department has paid their bill or not.

If post.course.departmentid has the option set to `option.department.paid = TRUE` it will show the content of a page, if not display a error text.

I´m sorry - its probably a stupid question but my head is far off today and the deadline for the project is closing up.

UPDATE!
I try to explain better.
Based on the first query and extracted fields I want to filter a new query.

ie

```
$querystr = "
SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'kursid' 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = " . $KURS_ID . " 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'course'
 ";

 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);


$querystrRegion = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'avdelingid' 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = " . get_field('regionid') . " 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'region'
 ";

$regions = $wpdb->get_results($querystrRegion, OBJECT);

?>
```

Comment: Can you include some code? Also, it is a little vague what you are looking for. Are you looking for the sql or are you having trouble understanding what to do with the data?

Comment: Hi @Jenn! I´ve tried to explain it a little better.